# Многопоточное чтение большого файла (превышающего Ram)

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Сразу предупреждаю, вопрос в рамках данного мне тестового задания для трудоустройства джуном, Прошу сильно палками не бить и хотя бы направить по нужному пути. Задание ограничено .Net 3.5

Собственно вопрос:

Имеем файл размером более 30гб, стоит задача правильно сжать его.
Планируемый алгоритм:

1. Запускаем два FileStream для чтения/записи.
2. Читаем файл небольшими порциями (по 10 мб) и записываем их в массив исходных данных
3. запускаем парочку потоков, которые будут забирать из этого массива блоки, сжимать их и помещать в массив сжатых данных.
4. FileStream для записи подхватывает блоки из массива сжатых данных и записывает их в файл.

Возникает сразу несколько вопросов:

1. Если Файл превышает размер RAM, значит я не могу содержать в памяти массив с блоками этого огромного фала, так как он там не поместится.
2. Даже если каким-то образом удастся реализовать удаление уже сжатых блоков из исходного массива, проблема сохранится в массиве сжатых блоков.
3. Многопоточность даже в два потока не гарантирует, что блоки первого и второго массива сохранят свои места, потоки могут работать с разной скоростью. Соответственно на выходе получается каша.

Итог печален, алгоритм нужно предать анафеме.

Каким должен быть правильный алгоритм, чтобы обработка производилась в несколько потоков и количество обрабатываемых данных помещалось в RAM???

UPD^^ 
Со свежими мыслями в голове появилась мысль использовать ресурсы харда.
Но к сожалению тонны прочтения информации FileStream не дали понимания того, что же получается на выходе, при попытке использовать FileStream.Read(), и можно ли это использовать в данном контексте.

UPD^^
Для сжатия требуется использовать GZipStream

Comment: Вот был вопрос, как объединить несколько блоков, сжатых по-отдельности: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744692/concatenate-multiple-zlib-compressed-data-streams-into-a-single-stream-efficient Несмотря на то, что вопрос касался zlib, и там отвечает Mark Adler - один из авторов zlib, тема так до конца и не раскрыта. Жестковатая задачка какая-то для джуна.

Comment: Многопоточная упаковка невозможна так просто, если у вас не блочный алгоритм упаковки (то есть, упаковывает блоки по одному). Смиритесь.

Comment: Или потребуйте утроения зарплаты и напишите собственный алгоритм упаковки.

Comment: Или используйте что-то вроде https://github.com/force-net/blazer - он хотя и не многопоточный, но как уже было сказано многопоточность здесь бессмысленна.

Comment: Хотя, посмотрел еще раз свою же ссылку http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744692/concatenate-multiple-zlib-compressed-data-streams-into-a-single-stream-efficient Для вашей задачи тема там вполне раскрыта даже, что касается именно компрессии, а вот с потоками и файлами - давайте сами.

Comment: А если использовать вместо RAM бинарник... ?

Comment: >>Имеем файл размером более 30гб, стоит задача правильно сжать его - для начала, уточните вопрос: что означает "правильно сжать", и зачем нужно грузить сразу все в RAM???
Скажем так: если не оговорен выходной формат (например, совместимость со стандартным zip), то все сильно проще. Делите длину файла на n (или nn) кусков == количеству требуемых тредов, в начале каждого треда делаете Seek(нужная_позиция), и сжимаете по кусочкам, считывая блоками по 4096 (или сколько угодно) байт. Как я понимаю, именно такую реализацию требует от вас работодатель?

Comment: Код за вас писать не буду: это неэтично, и такой код пишется за 10-15 минут с отладкой максимум во время собеседования.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую

Comment: @SeNS: Эээ... Ну сжали вы кусочки, а что потом с ними делать? Сконкатенировать? Вы думаете, получится валидный архив?

Comment: @VladD, вроде можно для gzip.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov: Ну это нетривиальная особенность формата, раз, и автор нигде не упоминает точный формат, два.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я добавлю в вопрос. Для решения задачи необходимо использовать GZipStream

Comment: @Garrus_En, дело в том, что zlib и так может сжать огромный файл, пользуясь небольшим количеством памяти - просто поблочно. Делать потоки имеет смысл только для ускорения при нескольких ядрах процессора. А с памятью и тем, что файл большой - этой проблемы и так нет. Вы правильно вообще поняли задачу или про потоки это вы уже сами придумали?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Вот как раз то, как выполнить в большом количестве потоков сжатие GZip, я так и не понял

Comment: @Garrus_En, может поможет вот это: http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#file-format

Comment: Не очень хорош этот формат для параллельной обработки (особенно распаковки). Может [тут](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/) что-то получше?

Comment: Господа, а если хранить части файла в очереди, из которой потоки будут сжимать и передавать блоки в поток записи. ВОПРОС!!! каким образом можно хранить прочитанные FileStream'ом байты